# Python, Pandas: Calculate Spearman Correlation on 4000 observations efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have a DataFrame with 2000 rows and 4000 columns (observations). I want to calculate the spearman correlation row-wise. Currently I´m using:

```
df.T.corr(method="spearman")
```

It seems to take a very long time (20min and still not finished).

Is there a more efficient module?

Can I preprocess the DataFrame to speed things up?

UPDATE: Using scipy.stats.spearmanr is 20x faster

```
SCC, pval = scp.spearmanr(df, axis=1)
SCC = pd.DataFrame(SCC, index=df.index, columns=df.index)
```

Comment: you may want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077080/calculate-special-correlation-distance-matrix-faster)

Comment: Probably you have answered your own question.  Often when you can do something in numpy/scipy it will be significantly faster than pandas (b/c pandas is much more general, but at the cost of some processing overhead).  Possibly you could get a speedup with cython or numba, but for a standard calculation like this, using the default numpy/scipy function is probably pretty close to maximum efficiency.  (in the link from @maxu there are no timings so hard to say if cython buys much.  I tend to doubt it, but you could certainly give it a try, or numba)

Comment: The faster spearmanr could be wrong. Please find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51386399/python-scipy-spearman-correlation-for-matrix-does-not-match-two-array-correlatio

Comment: The problem of rowbased spearman on two dfs is solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52371329/fast-spearman-correlation-between-two-pandas-dataframes/59072032#59072032